# How to Setup Default SSRS Report Variables

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have many reports which use a set of the same report variables:

[image]

Is there any possibility not to insert them each time manually when creating a new report? Or may be there is a possibility to share these variables between reports as , for instance, DataSources?

Can be used for this purpose assemblies?

Comment: [SSRS Templates](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2649/creating-a-reporting-service-report-template/)

Comment: Thank you! It seem that it is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it's seems you're looking for a subreport. Sub Report is a tool available in the toolbox in SSRS. It allows you to create a report that can in included in all your other reports without have to rebuild the structure.

Once you've created your report in the sub report properties just specify the report and include the parameters used for the report (if any) see below:

[image]

If that's not what you looking for, then maybe  it's shared data sets you're looking for.

Let me know if it's something completely different and I may be able to provide alternative solutions.

Thanks

Gav

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not talking about subreports. I talk about fast insert report variables into different reports, which are not connected. These variables set color palette in reports.